# Best place/price to get my Nikon D80 serviced?

Tags: nikon, repair, service-recommendation, error

I have had my D80 for 4 years now, and it has been working perfectly. I haven't used it for the past 2 months, and when I took it out last week I found out that it is broken. The LCD flashes "Err" when I try to focus or take a photo. The shutter works OK. Camera does not seem to be able to focus. This happens with two lenses. I did try cleaning the lens contacts, but that did not help. Also tried resetting the camera. At this point I am assuming something is broken.

What is the best place to have this repaired? Send it in to Nikon directly, or use a camera shop authorized to do the repairs? Where will I get the best service? the best price? I read somewhere online that Nikon repairs from them directly can run easily over $200. To me that seems a bit insane, given that that is probably more then half the market cost of my camera as it is right now.

Comment: What lenses are you using? are they AF-S (internal motor) or the older/cheaper ones driven from the camera?

Comment: AF-S. Both of them. One is a 18-55 I think, another one I don't remember, it's a zoom lens, don't use it much.

Comment: Very odd... do you have access to an older non AF-S lens to try?

Comment: No, I don't :/ From playing around with the camera it seems that the lens (either one) is not being recognized at all. Even weirder, I didn't drop my camera or subject it to moisture or heat or anything like that. Just kept it in the closet for a couple months and it quit on me. Is there any other way to try to "reset" it other than the reset button in the cable console and taking the battery out for some time?

Comment: Do you know what it could be?

Answer (score 1):

Take it to Nikon. Check their website for a local repair and service centre, if there's nothing nearby you may need to post/courier it. Nikon may make some small fixes free of charge and aren't always as expensive as you fear.

Alternatively take it to a friendly camera shop as you've already realised.

Edit: Did you try charging the battery? You'll get similar problems with flat battery.

Answer (score 1):

I live in Pa and have dealt with Nikon repairs at the Melville, NY(State) facility many times. I'll try to look into the ERR message and a possible solution.

The least convenient option that I can think of is to send everything to Nikon. You can visit their website to supply the necessary information, and they will give you a quote before repair (mine were covered under warranty, perhaps it would be reasonable enough to get done or if not perhaps the price of inspection/postage & insurance would be reasonable enough to give it a try).

One final option is to call 1-800-Nikon-US for support. 7 days a week from 8am to 2am.